# custom location and level for apache logs

Tags: apache-2.4, logging, .htaccess, hosting, web-hosting

On a payed hosting server, on which, I cannot access apache logs, I also have problems with website, website wasn't made by me, but now all troubles are in my head and I need to debug it, so

Is there a solution (like statements in .htaccess, maybe php functions ... site is made in php and not everything is working right) that will make apache record logs in a custom location (like my hosting folder that I can access with ftp), and (maybe) change log level ? (hosting server give me access to some logs, but, very, very few entries in it, so I guess is set on critical level, and I would need debug level)

THANK YOU !

PS excuse my English, I just hope what I'm asking is clear, I really need help with this one !

Comment: It's all in the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html)

Comment: not to poke you in the eye, but you should try in a "local" server you can admin and test first before going to "production" in a shared webhosting, so you know before hand what will happen, what to expect and how to configure everything. This thing about going blind to production server to which you don't have any access whatsoever for a minimum troubleshooting will just cause you headaches and frustration.